# Sessions not working in ruby on rails login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple login function, based on ruby on rails. The problem is, that the value for session[:username] seems to be always empty, because the method asking for this always responds true. If I remove this part, the place where the username should be displayed is empty. All important codes can be found below. For any other information ask me.

show_controller.rb:

```
class ShowController < ApplicationController
def login
@fehler1 = false
@fehler2 = false
if params[:username] != nil
    if User.find_by_username(params[:username]) == nil
        @fehler1 = true

    elsif User.find_by_username(params[:username]).pass == params[:pass]
        session[:username] = params[:username]
        redirect_to(:action => 'welcome')
    else
        @fehler2 = true
    end
end
end

def welcome
@fehler = false
if params[:logout] != nil
    session[:username] = nil
  redirect_to(:action => 'login')
end
if session[:username] == nil
    @fehler = true
else
    @username = session[:username]
end
end
end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

login.html.erb

```
<h3>login</h3>
<% if @fehler1 %>
<font color="red"><b>User existiert nicht!<br /></b></font>
<% elsif @fehler2 %>
<font color="red"><b>Falsches Passwort!<br /> </b></font>
<% end %>
<p>Hier können sie sich anmelden!</p>
<form action="/show/login" method="post">
<table width="30%">
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Passwort:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

welcome.html.erb:

```
<% if @fehler %>
<font color="red"><b>Sie sind nicht eingeloggt!<br></b></font>
<a href="/show/login">Hier geht es zum login</a><br>
<% else %>
<h2>Willkommen <%= @username %></h2>
<form action="/show/welcome" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="logout" value="true">
<input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
<% end %>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'thread_safe', '0.2.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I'm using rails version 4.0.0rc2 and ruby version 1.9.3p429. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So you get redirected to welcome correctly?

Comment: Baloo Yes, I get redirected correctly. The problem is, that, as I said, the welcome page shows the wrong text, probably because the information about the username is not stored properly or isn't saved at all.

Answer (score 0):

This, in my opinion, is a nicer way to do your controller code (assuming you still want the @fehler stuff all over the place):

```
class ShowController < ApplicationController
  def login
    @fehler1 = false
    @fehler2 = false
    if params[:username]
      if @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
        if @user.pass == params[:pass]
          session[:username] = params[:username]
          redirect_to(:action => 'welcome')   
        else
          @fehler2 = true
        end         
      else
        @fehler1 = true
      end
    end
  end

  def welcome
    @fehler = false
    if params[:logout]
      session[:username] = nil
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    end
    if session[:username]
      @username = session[:username]
    else
      @fehler = true 
    end
  end
end
```

It's cleaner and more readable to say `if params[:username]` than `if params[:username] != nil`

Does that make any difference?

Comment: Certainly more readable.  Presumably looking at `@fehler` in welcome action that could be replaced by just checking to see if `@username` is blank in the view as well

Comment: First of all thanks for your help... but it sadly makes no difference in the end, except the fact that its more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the user logged in and setting up their session is only one issue.  A larger, more complicated, and extremely critical part of this process is security.

The code you have presented is **not** secure:

```
User.find_by_username(params[:username]).pass == params[:pass]
```

...means you plan to store the users password uncrypted.  If your server is compromised, raw user passwords could be recovered by a hacker.  Which the hacker could then potentially use to login to other services (since many users use the same password for everything).

The devise gem was designed to handle logins, session creation, etc in a secure fashion, see:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

...for more details.

Comment: As this funktion is going to be a part of a school project and will never go public, there shouldn't be a problem about the security.

Comment: Checkout devise anyway, it will probably save you some time.

Comment: Well, I'm a total beginner in RoR and I guess, I won't understand that much about the gem. As the project has to be completed soon, I just want to fix the Version I have. Maybe I will later take the time to work out how devise works and use it on further projects or improve this one, but for now I only want this to work. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Throw "raise params.inspect" at the beginning of the login method, and try posting.  This will raise an error you will see in the terminal showing what the value of params is...and whether or not it contains username.

Comment: says the following (sorry about the form):

RuntimeError in ShowController#login 
{"controller"=>"show", "action"=>"login"}
Extracted source (around line #3): 
1 class ShowController < ApplicationController
2 def login
3 raise params.inspect
4 @fehler1 = false
5 @fehler2 = false
6 if params[:username]

Rails.root: C:/Users/Sebi/Documents/GitHub/Main/login
app/controllers/show_controller.rb:3:in `login'
Request Parameters:
None
Response Headers:
None

Comment: So you're not passing the username (doesnt show up in the params).  Double-check your html, make sure you have a <form></form> around your inputs, they are named correctly etc.  Try inspecting the username input using firebug, or chrome inspector or whatever browser youre on

Comment: checked the HTML for about 90 mins now... no Error found, <form> nad </form> is where it belongs. firebug says this when inspecting username input: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4146

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I tried setting session value in string key. Some how the session does not care about symbol key, it takes only string key.

```
 session["username"] =  params[:username]
```